# I can load resources on demand in an extremely large AngularJS app, but is there any way to unload them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory, requirejs

So, I have been developing a very large AngularJS app wherein there are many smaller, modular applications (such as a module to look up user profiles, a module to parse and view an RSS feed,  a module to view a complex map, etc).

Currently, there is a core framework being loaded in as well as dependencies (such as AngularJS) and a base definition of each module, its routes and its dependencies. When a route  is accessed, I use RequireJS to load the module's dependencies, including the controller and services that route needs.

As the user navigates through the applications, more and more javascript gets loaded, making the app get slower. This is especially noticeable when the user accesses a complicated module, such as the maps module.

Also, I've noticed that if I load a view, load data into the view, scroll through the data, then leave the module and come back to it, the view is unchanged (the data is still there and the scroll position remains).

I seem to be able to load resources "on demand" but I can not find a way to unload them. Is there any way to unload views/controllers/services when they are no longer needed in an AngularJS app?

Comment: I believe you can use $destroy

Comment: $destroy is just an event that gets fired when the scope is removed from its parent. I'd still have to actually do things in the $destroy event function, but I'm not sure what I can do to remove these things from memory. Controllers/services/directives/etc seem to be permanently attached to Angular once loaded.